# How to change the integer to string in a lookup table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot understand why joining tables are so difficult for me... But i would like to change a foreign key (`platform_id`) to the name from the lookup table. Dont know if this is the best approache, but should give me the best scaling options in the future.

Table companys

```
+----+--------+-------------+
| id |  name  | platform_id |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 | apple  |           1 |
|  2 | google |           2 |
+----+--------+-------------+
```

Table platforms

```
+----+----------+-------------------+
| id |   name   |       data        |
+----+----------+-------------------+
|  1 | Software | {'market cap':''} |
|  2 | Retail   | {'market cap':''} |
|  3 | Medicin  | {'market cap':''} |
+----+----------+-------------------+
```

Expected result

```
+----+--------+-------------+
| id |  name  | platform_id |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 | apple  | software    |
|  2 | google | retail      |
+----+--------+-------------+
```

What if i would like to also have the `data` column from `platsforms` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOIN` & create a view :

```
CREATE VIEW company_view 
AS 
   SELECT c.id, c.name, p.name as platform_id, p.data
   FROM company c INNER JOIN
        platform p
        ON p.id = c.platform_id;
```

If you want to change foreign key constraint to string value instead of `platform_id`. So, it is not advisable. Think if you need to change the name of platforms, you need to change ever where instead of one table.

Comment: Nice! How about if i would like the `data` column in the join as well?

Comment: @Adam. . . Add column in `SELECT` statement . Drop view & re-create.